# My powershell script is printing a '1' before my expected output. Why?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I wrote a simple powershell script that checks the number of tickets in a PSA service board and outputs the number of tickets and a color associated with it. However, my script is printing a '1' before the results. I am very new to powershell, and I can't seem to find the line that would print this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
$SqlServer = "server"
$SqlCatalog = "database"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_rpt_Service WHERE Board_Name = 'Traige' AND Parent = ''"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SqlServer; Database = $SqlCatalog; uid = user; pwd = pass"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$value = $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
$color = "Red"
if($value -lt 4){
$color = "Yellow"
}
if($value -lt 1){
$color = "Green"
}

$obj = new-object System.object
add-member -inputobject $obj -membertype NoteProperty -Name Tickets -value $value
add-member -inputobject $obj -membertype NoteProperty -Name Color -value $color 
$obj
```

Comment: $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null  I guess the number of rows returned is 1

Comment: Thank you! If you make your comment an answer, I will mark it as correct! I did not realize that filling a dataset would automatically print. Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null
```

Read here about [DbDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx) and its return value:

Type: System.Int32
The number of rows successfully added to or refreshed in the DataSet. This does not include rows affected by statements that do not return rows.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative that casts to void without using the pipeline. The pipeline should be avoided for performance reasons.

```
[void] $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to narrow it down to the actual line by injecting some lines that just print out some text. Once you find the actual line, you can pipe it through the "out-null" commandlet in order to suppress the output.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315279.aspx