# Console text in PowerShell Export-Csv command

Tags: powershell

I use `Export-Csv` command to export database tables, but it prints the lines count that has been exported for each table in the console. I didn't find any parameters for the command to prevent that.

```
$server = "USER\SQLEXPRESS"
$database = "database_test"
$tablequery = "SELECT name from sys.tables"

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

$DriveName = (Get-Location).Drive.Name
$extractDir = md -Force "$($DriveName):\csv\files"

# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $connection.open();
    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])]"
    $command.Connection = $connection

    (Get-Culture).NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = '.'
    (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $extractFile = "$($extractDir)\$($Row[0]).csv"
    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Example of an exported CSV:

```
"vat_id","category_id","vat_code"
"1","1","1"
"2","1","2"
"3","1","3"
"4","1","4"
"5","1","5"
"19","1","6"
"2345","1","8"
"2346","1","9"
"2347","1","10"
```

Comment: Can you add example line of what you receive in `.csv` file? Looks like simple `Select-Object` would do the job.

Comment: @robdy I added an example, but the problem isn't with the content of the csv, But the lines count printed in the console, I just don't want the lines count to be printed in the console.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536005/9902555)

Comment: It solved my problem.